# PHP Syntax Error With jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using DreamWeaver and I get this error from time to time and cannot figure out what is causing it.

When I add a little bit of jQuery from scripts I want into a php file, DW will tell me there is a syntax error. Here is where it says my error is(with a few lines before and after it):

```
   echo '
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';

   echo '
      <script type="text/javascript">
       (function( $, document, window, undefined ) {

           \'use strict\';
```

I don't understand it. Why is it saying there is a syntax error?

Comment: If this is everything, there is an unclosed single quote before the `;` in `use strict` Should have been `\'use strict\'';`

Comment: because there is a syntax error

Answer (score 5):

You're not terminating your last `echo` statement.

```
  echo '
      <script type="text/javascript">
       (function( $, document, window, undefined ) {

           \'use strict\'';
```

Comment: Yes, that seems obvious, but the original script doesn't have that. The script is actually jmPress.js. I cannot find a file on the net that isn't minified to show you what I mean, and it's just too long to post here. If I do as suggested, it just bumps the error down to everything else.

Comment: @DravenVestatt So you're asking us help you debug code we don't have?

Comment: Here is the script, untouched: http://jsfiddle.net/8aZrS/ . Wouldn't doing as suggested break the script?